# Minha variável com useSelector está printando undefined mesmo quando o reducer já retornou o valor

Tags: react, redux

Possuo esse saga que realiza uma requisição http e realiza um dispatch no meu reducer:

```
// worker Saga: will be fired on GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST actions
function* fetchFiliais(action) {
    try {
        const data = yield call(LoginServices.fetchFiliaisApi);
        yield put(allActions.loginActions.receiveFilialData(data));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_FILIAIS_FAILED', message: e.message})
    }
}

/*
  Starts fetchFiliais on each dispatched `GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST` action.
*/

export default function* loginSaga() {
    yield takeEvery("GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST", fetchFiliais);
}
```

No meu componente de login eu realizo um dispatch para chamar esse saga:

```
const Login = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const filiais = useSelector(state => state.filiais)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type: 'GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST'})
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log(filiais); }, 5000);
  }, [dispatch, filiais])
```

Esse é meu reducer. No meu console.log() está printando corretamente o type e payload, inclusive está printando "enter correct case":

```
const currentUser = (state = {}, action) => {
    console.log(action.type)
    console.log(action.payload)

    switch(action.type){
        case "SET_USER":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                loggedIn: true
            }
        case "LOG_OUT":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: {},
                loggedIn: false
            }
        case "RECEIVE_FILIAL_DATA":
            console.log('enter correct case')
            return {
                ...state,
                filiais: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
```

Porém meu console.log() que coloquei na variável filiais está printando undefined. Porque?

Esse é meu index.js:

```
import loginSaga from './pages/login/login-form/saga'

// create the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)

// then run the saga
sagaMiddleware.run(loginSaga)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Esse é meu root Reducer:

```
import currentUser from './login'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    currentUser
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Tenta substituir o teu `const filiais = useSelector(state => state.filiais)` por `const filiais = useSelector(state => state.currentUser.filiais)` e diz o que acontece, por favor...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar printa o valor correto porém o useEffect é chamado diversas vezes, se eu tirar a variável dispatch e filiais do segundo parametro do useEffect é chamado apenas uma vez, porém o valor não é printado...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem dois problemas não relacionados no seu código, então vou dividir a resposta em partes:

## Como funciona o seu estado redux

Primeiro, você está tentando buscar o valor de filias diretamente no seu reducer com a linha:

```js
const filiais = useSelector(state => state.filiais)
```

o seu estado, segundo você descreveu na pergunta, na verdade é composto por um estado superior `currentUser` e esse conterá `loggedIn`, `filias` e `user`. Logo, para acessar filias pelo `useSelector`, você precisa utilizar:

```js
 const filiais = useSelector(state => state.currentUser.filiais)
```

Isso retornará, efetivamente, as filias do estado redux.

## O useEffect NÃO deve ser executado sempre

Perceba que no seu componente Login, você está executando o `useEffect` sempre que houver uma alteração no `dispatch` e nas `filias`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({type: 'GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST'})
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log(filiais); }, 5000);
}, [dispatch, filiais]) //Aqui você atrelá efeitos quando houverem alterações em dispatch ou filias
```

No entanto, perceba que no corpo desse `useEffect` você lança uma requisição de filiais, o que, se finalizada com sucesso, causará uma alteração em filiais, o que consequentemente disparará o hook de efeito, que lançará o dispatch, que causará a alteração de filiais em caso de sucesso, que... Entende? Isso fará com que o seu programa fique constantemente lançando requisições para atualizar filias até que aconteça uma falha.
Para resolver esse problema é preciso executar o efeito **apenas na criação** do seu componente, para isso, você deve atualizar o `useEffect` para:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({type: 'GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST'})
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log(filiais); }, 5000);
}, [])
```

Já que quando você atrela um vetor vazio ao useEffect, ele executará apenas na montagem do componente (análogo ao antigo `componentDidMount()`), isso fará que suas filias sejam atualizadas apenas uma vez e, consequentemente, ou você terá todas as filias ou deverá fazer o tratamento de erros, criando a ação necessária para isso no seu reducer (com a ação `FETCH_FILIAIS_FAILED` que você criou).

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente explicação.
Quando eu removo o dispatch e filiais do [] meu console.log() volta a ser undefined. Outra coisa que tenho que fazer quando retiro eles é adicionar um comentário para o meu esLint:   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
você pode me ajudar quanto a esse undefined?

Comment: Na verdade está entrando no meu reducer no case "RECEIVE_FILIAL_DATA" porém é printado undefined

Comment: O que é undefined? O payload ou filiais? Lembrando que se a sua requisição demorar mais de 5s para ser processada, de fato será impresso undefined no console.log do timeout...

Comment: Sobre a regra do exhaustive-deps, existe uma thread de [discussão bem longa no create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880) sobre suprimir essa regra quando você **de fato** não precisa que o efeito seja assistido pela aplicação. (: